# Compute $\ Var(X+Y+Z) $ where $\ X,Y,Z \sim Binomial $

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

Suppose I throw 3 fair dice 30 times.

Let,

X = no' of throws in which we don't get  4 
Y = no' of throws in which we get 4 in only one die (out of 3) 
Z = no' of throws in which we get 4 in exactly two dice (out of 3)

Compute $\ Var(X+Y+Z) $

by definition $\ Var(X+Y+Z) = E[(X+Y+Z)^2] + (E[X+Y+Z])^2 $

$\ E[X+Y+Z] = E[X] + E[Y] + E[Z] = 29.8611$  because each variable of a multinomial distribution is of binomial distribution. so I know $\ (E[X+Y+Z])^2 = 29.8611^2 $ but how do I calculate $\ E[(X+Y+Z)^2] $ ?

Suggestions please?

Comment: Consider the probability of getting three $4$s and then consider $Var(n-X-Y-Z)$

Comment: Can I just set new variable $\ W = $ no' of throws in which I get up to two 4's and then calculate the variance of $\ W $ as it is binomial variable?

Comment: Yes - that works very well since each set of throws is independent and gives a yes/no answer to "up to two 4s"

Answer (score 1):

These $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are strongly related to each other - to the point where we'd rather not work with them directly in calculating the variance. In particular, $X+Y+Z+W=30$, where $W$ is the number of throws in which all three dice come up fours. The variance of $X+Y+Z$ is the same as that of $W$. Can you calculate that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why is the variance of $\ X+Y+Z $ be the same as that of $\ W $ ?

Comment: Another poster got there while I was sleeping in more detail, but it's a general rule; the variance of $aX+b$ is $|a|^2$ times the variance of $X$ for constants $a$ and $b$. We write $X+Y+Z=30-W$ and apply that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the notation from @jmerry, let $W$ be the number of tosses in which all 3 dice show 4. Thus, $X+Y+Z+W=30$, i.e. $X+Y+Z=30-W$ implying $Var(X+Y+Z)=Var(30-W)$.

Let's consider $Q=30-W$.

$\mathbb{E}[Q] = 30-\mathbb{E}[W]$

$\mathbb{E}[Q^2] = 900 + \mathbb{E}[W^2] - 60\mathbb{E}[W]$

$Var[Q] =  \mathbb{E}[Q^2] - \mathbb{E}[Q]^2$

$=900 + \mathbb{E}[W^2] - 60\mathbb{E}[W] - (30-\mathbb{E}[W])^2$

$=\mathbb{E}[W^2] -\mathbb{E}[W]^2$

$=Var(W)$ (by definition)

Thus, $Var(30-W) = Var(W) = Var(X+Y+Z)$.

$W$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $N=30$ and $p = \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^3$. You can calculate the variance as $Np(1-p)$.